# Connecting through openVPN with Python using config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openvpn

I am trying to gather data from a computer running in another country. With the Linux terminal, I can use openVPN with the .ovpn file to connect. However, to make automated API calls, I want to use Python.

Is there a way to connect through Python and getting the connection details from the .opvn file? A bit similar to SSHForwarder.

Something like this:

```
from openvpn_api import VPN
v = VPN('199.249.9.9', 1194)
with v.connection():
    print(v.release)
```

Much appreciated!

Rutger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just run console command from your script by `subprocess.run(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)`.

Args should be a list like this: `['sudo', '/usr/local/sbin/openvpn',  '--config',  home + '/path/to/config.ovpn']`

For example:

```
import subprocess, os

home = os.environ["HOME"]
args = [
'sudo',
'/Mike/local/sbin/openvpn',
'--config',
home + '/Mike/Downloads/office.ovpn'
    ]
r = subprocess.run(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
...
# your code which needs to be connected to openvpn
...
# kill connection
r.stdout
```

One another (easier) way is to use subprocess.Popen():

```
import subprocess, psutil

# define function to kill connection
def kill(proc_pid):
    process = psutil.Process(proc_pid)
    for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
        proc.kill()
    process.kill()

# use shell command to connect openvpn
r = subprocess.Popen(shell_command, shell=True)

...
# your code
...

# kill connection
kill(r.pid)
```

Comment: I like this solution, hadn't thought of that! Thanks!